# Spring boot application that can handle both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 messages

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, soap

I have got wsdl with two bindings defined. One for SOAP 1.1. and one for SOAP 1.2. I have generated contract first web service using Spring-WS, Spring boot and Maven using this WSDL. (Using this [tutorial](https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-ws-soap-web-service-consumer-provider-wsdl-example.html).)

My question is: can I make one enpoint, that is able to serve both types of messages at once? As far as I know, there is only possibility to handle only one type of messages at the same time, by setting messageFactory.setSoapVersion().

```
@Bean
public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
    messageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_12);
    messageFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return messageFactory;
}
```